# reading a large file and processing section by section

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a large text file which has a format like:

> SECTION START ... ... ... SECTION END SECTION START ... ... ...
>   SECTION END ....

I want to parse the file and consume it section by section, however I don't want to hold the entire content in memory, I want to read a section and do some operations to the section, e.g. insert it to a DB, then discard it and continue to read the next section, how should I do this in a functional way? I can only come up with some implementations by manipulating mutable variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always solve these sorts of problems by writing a (tail) recursive function*

```
def parseLines(
  in: Iterator[String],
  thisSection: List[String] = Nil,
  results: List[Foo] = Nil
): List[Foo] = {
  if (!in.hasNext) results.reverse
  else in.next match {
    case "SECTION END" =>
      val section = thisSection.reverse.drop(1)
      // Do something with data
      val foo = // whatever you need to store from this section
      parseLines(in, Nil, foo :: results)
    case s =>
      parseLines(in, s :: thisSection, results)
  }
}
```

but it's not always better to do this than to use mutable variables.  The key is to keep your mutability well-guarded so the changing state doesn't leak out and complicate the logic in the rest of your program.  Adding an accumulator variable inside a method like this instead of making it recursive is perfectly okay too; pick whichever makes the logic clearer.

*<sup>It had better be tail-recursive or the stack will overflow.  Use the `@tailrec` annotation to make sure.</sup>